# Publishing data with information from another collection in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, underscore.js, aggregation-framework

I have two collections: Meta and the normal users collection. The Meta collection has the following structure:

```
{
  userId: ObjectId,
  contacts: [Array],
  conversations: [Array]
}
```

Each user has a corresponding, distinct document in the Meta collection. Now I want to publish the users that belong in the current user's contacts or conversations array.

```
{
  userId: 123,
  contacts: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  conversations: ['a', 'e']
}
```

For user `123`, I want to publish user profile data for users a, b, c and e. Basically all the distinct values of the contacts and conversations array.

I tried merging the array and using `_.uniq' on the new array inside the publish function but I need this to be reactive so when a user adds a new contact, the contact list can update reactively. Something tells me Mongo's aggregation framework can help but I'm not sure how to use it with Meteor. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [reactive-publish](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-publish) package (I am one of authors):

```
Meteor.publish('profiles', function (userId) {
  this.autorun(function (computation) {
    var meta = Meta.findOne({userId: userId}, {fields: {contacts: 1, conversations: 1}});
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: meta.contacts.concat(meta.conversations)}}, {fields: {profile: 1}});
  });
});
```

The important detail is that you have to limit the first query only to `contacts` and `conversations` fields, otherwise `autorun` would be rerun every time any field in the `Meta` document changes.

You should probably also add some checks, like what if corresponding `Meta` document does not exist. Or if fields (arrays) do not exist.